# How to add company name field in admin console (new user) alfresco community?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using Alfresco Community 5.0.d and it does not show the fields for company info.

If I search for user then it shows all details but don't let me add company info while creating a user.

So far I came across user.js file at /Applications/alfresco-5.0.d/tomcat/webapps/share/components/console but I'm not able to add the field for new user.

```
    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-companyname", Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");  // ADDED this but not showing in form.

    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-firstname", Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");
    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-email", Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");
    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-email", Alfresco.forms.validation.email, null, "change", parent._msg("Alfresco.forms.validation.email.message"));
    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-username", Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");
    form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-username", Alfresco.forms.validation.nodeName, null, "keyup", parent._msg("Alfresco.forms.validation.nodeName.message"));
```

Also I have added the key-value in personObj created in users.js as below.

```
var personObj =
         {
            userName: username,
            password: password,
            firstName: fnGetter("-create-firstname"),
            lastName: fnGetter("-create-lastname"),
            email: fnGetter("-create-email"),
            organization: fnGetter("-create-companyname"),
            disableAccount: Dom.get(me.id + "-create-disableaccount").checked,
            quota: quota,
            groups: groups
         };
```

PersonObj is:

```
personObj
disableAccount : false
email : "test@test.com"
firstName : "test"
groups : Array[0]
lastName : "test"
organisation : "test"   //added this key-value
password : "admin"
quota : -1
userName : "test_test"
```

But company name is not coming. Moreover, I have tried adding multiple user using [.csv file link](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/tasks/at-adminconsole-upload-users.html) and it does not show the company name (column name is Company as given in guide lines) but do show like mobile number, fax, etc.

Is this is a bug with Alfresco community 5.0.d?

Screenshot of new user form for reference.

[image: new user form]

I need to add company name field in above form of new user so it could be pre-populated for those new user's.

How could I add the company name field so it gets added to new user's profile?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a field which is already a property of user model.

In case of adding company field, follow below steps:

1. In users.get.properties file - Add below line.

> label.companyname=Company

2. In users.js file - Added fields company property for not null check and getting it's value followed with clearing the value after a valid entry.

`form.addValidation(parent.id + "-create-companyname",Alfresco.forms.validation.mandatory, null, "keyup");  // Add validation
organisation: fnGetter("-create-companyname"),  // Get company value
fnClearEl("-create-companyname");  // Clear company field`

3. In users.get.html.ftl file - Added div for company
   `<div class="field-row">
   <span class="crud-label">${msg("label.companyname")}:&nbsp;*</span> </div> <div class="field-row">
       <input class="crud-input" id="${el}-create-companyname" type="text" maxlength="100" /> 
   </div>`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can add user company details using.
Javascript. example

```
var x =people.getPerson("admin");
logger.log(x.properties["companyemail"]);
```

//getting the current Company email

```
x.properties["companyemail"]="test@google.com";
```

//setting new company email

```
logger.log(x.properties["companyemail"]);
```

//getting the new Company email

```
companytelephone
companyaddress2
companyaddress1
companyfax
companyemail
companypostcode
```

These are the some properties of user comapny

Comment: I dont want to get details of a user but how to add field of company name in new user form (for admin console.) Please see screenshot in post (Updated).

Comment: it is by default only visible for admin users.for normal users fields are not visible.

Comment: Its not visible for admin user. When admin go to user and create new user then in the form there is no company name field (which is there in user's full profile). As you see the screenshot, there is no company field and I want to add that field to the form so admin can provide the company name for the new user that he/she is creating. I hope this clears my query. let me know if any more info is required. Cheers